# Do you need a software firewall when using VPN?

Tags: vpn, firewall

How secure/vulnerable is a remote laptop with no firewall enabled but connected to the office through a VPN? The office has a network firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you do. Your main interface is still exposed to the internet. All the requests will come to your computer directly from the internet, not through a VPN.